# JavaFX HBox layout binding as Circle

Tags: javafx

I'm having a problem positioning JavaFX's HBox in a similar manner to Circle.

If using a circle shape it is possible to manually position it such that it is bound to a different node. This is what I've done until now, by having a Pane as the point of reference:

```
Pane node; //can be dragged around/resized
//...
Circle terminal = new Circle(10);
terminal.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
terminal.setFill(Color.GREEN);
terminal.centerXProperty().bind( node.layoutXProperty() );
terminal.centerYProperty().bind( node.layoutYProperty() );
```

The pane (node) functions as a graph node and can be dragged around and resized. The circle functions as a port/terminal for edge connections in the graph. Seeing that the node should have more than one the idea is to put the circles into an HBox that is attached/bound to the pane like the circle has until now. This makes it so that manual layout calculations are unnecessary when adding or removing ports, resizing the node, etc. So the code then used was:

```
Pane node; //can be dragged around/resized
//...
HBox terminalContainer = new HBox();
terminalContainer.layoutXProperty().bind( node.layoutXProperty() );
terminalContainer.layoutYProperty().bind( node.layoutYProperty() );
//... adding circles into HBox as scenegraph children
```

The only difference is swapping out the HBox for the Circle and using the layoutXProperty() as there is no centerXProperty(). But of course this fails, and the ports appear glued on to the top part of the containing frame, acting strangely. Is there a fix for this? I tried changing the parenting Pane to an anchorPane, this allowed to manually anchor down the HBox in the correct place, but caused issues with the resizing/dragging code.

Minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main2 extends Application {

    private AnchorPane component;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        component = new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(component, 1024, 768);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        //This works, but is hard to maintain
        Cell c1 = new Cell();
        Cell c2 = new Cell();
        Port p1 = new Port(c1);
        Port p2 = new Port(c2);
        component.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2, p1, p2);
        c1.relocate(150, 150);
        c2.relocate(550, 550);
        //This does not work, even if unbinding circles, but is simpler
        HBox pc1 = new HBox();
        HBox pc2 = new HBox();
        pc1.layoutXProperty().bind( c1.layoutXProperty() );
        pc1.layoutYProperty().bind( c1.layoutYProperty() );
        pc2.layoutXProperty().bind( c2.layoutXProperty() );
        pc2.layoutYProperty().bind( c2.layoutYProperty() );
        Port p3 = new Port(c1);
        Port p4 = new Port(c2);
        pc1.getChildren().add(p3);
        pc2.getChildren().add(p4);
        component.getChildren().addAll(pc1, pc2);
    }

    class Cell extends Pane {
        public Cell() {
            Rectangle view = new Rectangle(50,50);
            view.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
            view.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
            getChildren().add(view);
        }
    }

    class Port extends Pane {
        public Port(Cell owner) {
            Circle view = new Circle(10);
            view.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
            view.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            view.centerXProperty().bind( owner.layoutXProperty() );
            view.centerYProperty().bind( owner.layoutYProperty() );
            getChildren().add(view);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, was a typo in the code binding the layoutXProperty twice instead of the layoutYProperty *facepalm*